# Divide results based on percentage

Tags: process

I am writing the spacifications for a new feature in our application.
Now what we want to do is whenever a message for  trasfers is sent by client in a specific currency we need to divide between one or more banks.

80 % to bank A and 20% to bank B etc each time a transfer message is sent. We need to build this in our db (sql 2005) so that if the percentage change for us to be able to change that.
I am having difficulty  writing the spec for the calculation  of when the 80% of messages will be sent to BANK A and when the 20% will be sent to bank b based on the perecentage we have in our db. I initially thought of implenting a counter that counts the messages and then doing a calculation based on the percentage but not sure of the algorythm. can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the results to be guaranteed, you could simply base the routing on a random number generator:

```
var r = rand() // assume it yields a decimal between 0.0 and 1.0
if (r < 0.2) sendToBankB()
else         sendToBankA()
```

The above is obviously hard-coded and simplified for just two banks, but I think you could see how to generalize it for N banks with N percentages: sort by percentage and test the array in increasing order.

If you do need to be exact about it (send four to Bank A and the fifth always to Bank B) then I think you will need to implement a counter. The most important question in my mind for this is:

- If you have odd ratios that don't reduce nicely (say 51% and 49%), is it OK to send 51 to Bank A and then 49 to Bank B, or would you want to alternate sends up until the last?

In general, look to first reduce your ratios by dividing by the [greatest common divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor), and then either send the right number of messages to each bank sequentially, or shuffle all the results together along the same repetition period.

Comment: I d would need to be exact i.e 50-50, 80-20, 20-30-50. I think a counter would be required, the issue is how do you allocate "transfer messages" based on these percentages? i mean how would the programmer now that if i my counter is now at lets say 12 messages he would know that the percentage of 70 % for Bank A is met so the system will need to start allocating messages to BankB until the 30% is met. Or even if the percentage is 50-50 hwo will he now that the previous message was allocated to Bank a and the next will need to be allocated to bank b?